# Java prog to capture images from a webpage and output their links to an Excel file

Tags: java, html

I want a Java app that would capture all the images (and preferably data in other tags too) from a webpage and write their links to an excel file.

While I know my way around Excel files and Java, I was just wondering if there's any way to capture images from web pages.

A quick google search didnt help

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is.
Since images are in the source code, you can start from the simpliest solution - getting the page source, retrieve image links and download them.

[KISS](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_%28regu%C5%82a%29) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to parse the html of the webpage and get the links referring to images from respective html tags.

Comment: Try using URL and URLConnection class to get the html.